# CSS Back-ground Image Transparency

Tags: css, image

> background-image: url("../img/bluebubbles.png"), linear-gradient(to left, steelblue, #fff);

So i employed a "background-image" property using a url to a png image file and a linear-gradient property. What do i have to do to make my image blend in with the background?

Comment: Have you tried [background-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode)?

Answer (score 1):

you have [background-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode) property that you can use to achieve that blend. There are plenty of possibilities available it's a matter of testing and choose the one that better fit your project.